# "I didn't spend" vs "I didn't spent"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Which is the correct grammar? Which is correct?

Comment: Crosslinking: [English questions and negation with *do* in syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/english-questions-and-negation-with-do-in-syntax), [Question about interrogations in past tense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66850/question-about-interrogations-in-past-tense), and [What is the origin of the 'do' construction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/what-is-the-origin-of-the-do-construction)

Answer (score 5):

*I didn't spend* is correct. You must use the [infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive), not the [simple past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_past_%28English%29). (The helper verb *do* takes the simple past already.)

Answer (score 1):

The negation of *I spent* is built by adding the basic form of the verb (in this case *spend*) to the negation of *did*.

> I didn't spend.

*Spent* would be used in the present perfect.

> I have spent $100.
>   I have not spent $900.

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't spend" is correct. *Didn't* is already the past tense.