# Why do we use the base form of verbs instead of the past form in past tense questions?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, tenses, questions, do-support

In regard to this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/31972/20878), my question is similar but that answer is not clear. I want to know why we use base form of verb, e.g. 'go' to form the past tense instead of past form such as 'went'?

> Question: Did you go to a bank?  (Why we use 'go' here, rather than 'went'?)
>    Answer: I went to a bank.

Am I confusing verb forms with tenses? Please note that I'm not a native speaker so some clarification or reference on this would be helpful.

Comment: Related: [English questions and negation with *do* in syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/english-questions-and-negation-with-do-in-syntax), [“I didn't spend” vs “I didn't spent”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/i-didnt-spend-vs-i-didnt-spent), and [What is the origin of the 'do' construction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/what-is-the-origin-of-the-do-construction)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is that there is **at most one** tense marker in each clause.

There may be **no** tense markers, as in the gerund clause *going to the Moon* or the infinitive clause *to go to the Moon*; but there **can't** be more than **one**.

- In *I visited the bank* the single (past) tense marker is the ***-ed*** in *visited*.
- In *I did visit the bank* the single (past) tense marker is the ***did*** (instead of *do* or *does*).

It's spread out this way because Question Formation, Negative Formation, and a number of other syntactic rules all require there to be a [first auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf); and if there **is** no auxiliary verb (i.e, if there is only one verb) in the clause, then they all require [*Do*-Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) to provide that auxiliary verb.

Finally, the rules of English grammar require that the single tense marker goes on the first auxiliary verb, or on the main verb if there is no auxiliary verb. That's why it was on the single main verb before Do-Support; but afterwards, it has to go on the new auxiliary verb, which becomes *did*.

Silly, I know, but that's English syntax for you.

Comment: How can we recognize these tense markers for each tense?

Comment: I think the OP may be having trouble with the fact that English requires verb before subject in questions, but (unlike other Germanic languages) forbids all verbs except “be” (and sometimes “have”) from such inversions directly. We say “He goes”, but forbid “Goes he?”. Same in the simple past: “He went” is allowed, but “Went he?” is forbidden. To get past this prohibition, an auxiliary (do, be, or have) will be used in one way or another: “Does he go?”, and “Did he go?” It has nothing to do with past versus present, you see.

Comment: All auxiliary verbs commute in questions, including all modal auxiliaries (_may, might, must, can, could, shall, should, will, would,_ and sometimes _need_ and _dare_), _have_ of the Perfect, _be_ of the Progressive, and _be_ of the Passive. In that order. For details, see the [Verb Phrase Study Guide.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest answer is "because we do"... that's English grammar!

But perhaps I can offer something that will be more insightful. The following two sentences are equivalent in meaning (if not in emphasis):

> I *visited* the bank.
>   I *did visit* the bank.

You can mark past tense by placing the main verb in its past-tense form or by using the past-tense auxiliary *did*. In questions, we usually use the second of these so that we can perform the usual subject-auxiliary swap:

> *Did* you *visit* the bank?

So to sum up, English allows the past tense to be formed in two ways and your choice of which is dependent on the context.