# "How did you sorted among such large number of t-shirts?" Correct or not?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about interrogations in past tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66850/question-about-interrogations-in-past-tense)

I asked this question to a friend of mine and he said that you can't use "sorted" with "did". Is he correct? If yes, what is the correct grammatical sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right. You can't use "sorted" with "did". Hence, the correct sentence is:

> How did you **sort** among such a large number of t-shirts?

Plus, don't use "among" with "sort". You can say:

> How did you **sort** such a large number of t-shirts?
>
> How did you **sort out** such a large number of t-shirts?

Comment: I would remove the *among* as well.