# doesn't has to /have to

Tags: grammar

Why do we use *have* instead of *has* with *doesn't* like in the following sentence:

He **doesn't have**(not has) to go there.

Please explain the grammatical reason behind it.

Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking what the rule is, or why the rule is in place? In the former case, see the [linked question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66852/300) and the related questions linked from there, and read up on [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support). In the latter case, the answer is basically "just because", though some analysis can be found [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/english-questions-and-negation-with-do-in-syntax).

Comment: The above two links didn't answer my question. I just need to know why is it wrong to write like: "He doesn't has to do this" ? Why do we use "have to" with "doesn't"?

Comment: The reason is that auxiliary _do_ must be followed by the ***infinitive*** form of the verb, not by a form like _has_ that is inflected for tense, person, and number. Infinitives are called "infinitives" because they are **not** inflected; ***finite*** verbs are inflected, like _has_. It turns out that the infinitive form is the same as the present for for almost all English verbs (all except _be_), so _have_ could be either one. But _has_ is always inflected, so it can never follow _do_ (or a modal, or any other word that takes an infinitive).