# Describe the grammatical error in the sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

"I did went to the movie"
Describe the grammatical error in the sentence.
I know that it is wrong but I am not able to explain it to my younger brother.

Comment: You either say *I went* or *I did go*. If the emphatic *do* is used, it takes the  grammatical form upon itself (tense, number, person, etc.), leaving the semantic verb in bare infinitive.

Comment: ["The rule is that there is at most one tense marker in each clause."](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66852/300)