# Substituting "do" after modals

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

Occasionally I hear native English speakers, typically those from outside the U.S., say things like:

> Are you going to the concert this weekend?
>   Yeah, I might do.

That is, rather than saying *I might go* or just *I might*, substituting *do* for the verb when it'd otherwise be repeated or omitted after a modal. What's this called, how standard is it, and is it newer or older than the other forms? I just don't know how to search for something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic term for *do* standing in for a verb phrase is *pro-form do* or *proform do*. I'm not sure if there is technical term for when the *do* follows a modal verb, but I've seen it referred to as *British do*.

Your example sounds entirely natural to me. (*Yeah, I might do.*) That sort of construction (modal + pro-form do) is common in British English, but I gather it sounds weird to American ears.

Regarding how old it is, Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage says, "These are not recent idioms; they have been under attack and examination at least since Corbett 1823."

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I don't know what this specific informal use of *do* is called. The regular use of *do* as a substitute, in *"do I?"* and *"I do not"*, is I believe called *[do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)*.

I think your case is similar to *"could you give her this document too?" — "will do"*, which does sound American to my ears, perhaps southern U.S. or something.

What might also be relevant is why we omit some words but not others in ellipsis, and how we make our choice: to *"are you coming to the party?*, we could answer simply *"no"*, or *"no, I'm not"*, or *"no, I am not coming"*. Or even *"I might"*, *"I might come"* etc.

My guess would be that this usage of *"might do"* and *"will do"* is not old, though I am not sure.

> Modals have always differed from
>   ordinary verbs in Germanic, and in the
>   course of the history of English, they
>   have diverged from verbs even further,
>   to the point where they now belong to
>   a syntactic category of their
>   own.[1](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/box-modals.html)

The following question was also about do-support, but not specifically about your case: [English questions and negation with *do* in syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/english-questions-and-negation-with-do-in-syntax)

Comment: I always assumed that this was a short hand for "I <modal> do *that which you said*". The object is taken as understood from the context.

Comment: @Dmckee: You are probably right; but the same may very well apply to Jon's example, may it not do [so]? // (I called it non-standard because "I might" and "I will" is so much more... what is it? Traditional? Common? So hard to define standard.)

Comment: @Cerberus: Come to think of it, I don't think the *do* ever appears in questions, either affirmative or negative. I typically hear this spoken by English people specifically, especially in more urban accents, so I'd tend to agree that it's probably not all that old, but with English you never really know, right?

Comment: @Jon: Absolutely! I really don't know much about the spread of this usage, because I'm not often exposed to non-standard English.

Comment: I would say 'I might do' is probably more common in British English than 'I might'. It is not limited to 'urban' accents. To my Britannic ear 'I might' sounds wrong somehow. Dmckee is correct in saying it's essentially a shorthand version of 'I might do that'. 'I may do' is also used quite a bit.

Comment: I'm with Elendil; it sounds perfectly natural to me, and I don't really see how it's non-standard, even if a bit informal. There are also less formal versions like - ' can you write this report for me' - 'OK, will do'. But I don't think we ever use it with 'must'.

Comment: @Elendil, @Random: Oh, really? I had no idea it was so frequent. I don't think I hear it a lot, and I think I was taught it was wrong in school. But I'll replace "non-standard" with "informal", then. Elendil, I am even more surprised that "I might" should sound wrong to you.

Comment: Another British ear here: "I might do" and "I might" both sound fine to me (I think I might use them in different contexts but I can't easily put my finger on the difference!). The phrase "I might do so", though less frequent, is also acceptable.