# Subject /verb order in a question with implied answer or surprise

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

When you are surprised by a piece of information you have just learned, is it OK to ask the question without changing the subject or verb order?

Example:

> You really think Argentina has the best team in the world. But then you learn that it has scored fewer points than a few other teams, Brazil won more cups, etc. After learning the facts, would be OK to write / ask:

In response:

> So, Argentina is **not** the best team in the world?

It is not a rhetorical question, and it doesn't really imply an answer. The facts are created from the above sentence.

Comment: Related:  [Why do we invert word order when asking a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21018/26083),  [Does appending a question mark to a declarative sentence result in a valid sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/55972/26083),  and  [Is it OK to add a question mark to show inflection?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/34090/26083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally acceptable. It's a declarative question.  "It is acceptable to write it this way?"  "Yes, writing it this way is acceptable."

(In your facts, however, it should read "has scored fewer points than..." rather than "has scored less points than ..."