# Why must "not" frequently be paired with "do"?

Tags: grammaticality, negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [English questions and negation with *do* in syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/english-questions-and-negation-with-do-in-syntax)

I've always wondered why English insists on pairing *not* with *do*, when negating an action.  For example, you say:

> I **do** not like that coat.

Instead of:

> I not like that coat.

When you're not negating, however, there is no need for *do* (except that it can optionally be used as an intensifier):

> I like that coat.

[Dictionary.com describes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/not) the word *not* in this contect as an adverb.  Shouldn't it be OK just to add it in to the sentence on its own, so that one of the following should be acceptable?:

> I not like that coat.
>   I like not that coat.

Why must *do* be added before?

Comment: I'll leave others to speculate as to why, but "I like not that coat" would be a correct although unusual construction - probably more often used poetically.

Comment: The simple answer is "because it must". That's how English works. There _are_ deeper theoretical explanations, but there is no answer to the question of why English should have this property and other languages not.

Answer (score 0):

Technically `I like not that coat` is correct, and that formation is used occasionally, but it's exceedingly rare and really only [used for comedy value](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIhBXR7I-c4) <sup><sup>[YouTube video]</sup></sup> these days.

A more common alternative that doesn't use "do" would be to use a prefix to negate the verb, as in `I dislike that coat`.